# PHP glob-style matching

Tags: php, path, pattern-matching, glob

To keep things short, I wrote an access-control system.

One of the requirements of this system is to check whether a canonical/normalized path can be accessed or not by matching it against a pattern.

First thoughts would fall on PREG, problem is, the patterns are file-based, ie, similar to those accepted by `glob()`. Basically, it's just patterns containing `?` (match one arbitrary character) or `*` (match any character).

So in simple terms, I need to recreate `glob()`'s matching functionality on PHP.

Sample code:

```
function path_matches($path, $pattern){
    // ... ?
}

path_matches('path/index.php', 'path/*');        // true
path_matches('path2/', 'path/*');                // false
path_matches('path2/test.php', 'path2/*.php');   // true
```

A possible solution would be to convert `$pattern` into a regular expression than use `preg_match()`, is there any other way though?

**NB:** The reason why I can't use regex is that patterns will be written by non-programmers.

Comment: Why recreating glob() if it already exists in php ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: Uhuh, please read the question again. `glob()` works with actual paths, I need to recreate its pattern matching capability. I don't see how I can use `glob()` (on non-existent paths) for my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting to a regex seems like the best solution to me. All you need to do is convert `*` to `.*`, `?` to `.` and `preg_quote`. However it's not as simple as it may seem because it's a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem in terms of the order in which you do things.

I don't *like* this solution but it's the best I can come up with: use a regex to generate the regex.

```
function path_matches($path, $pattern, $ignoreCase = FALSE) {

  $expr = preg_replace_callback('/[\\\\^$.[\\]|()?*+{}\\-\\/]/', function($matches) {
    switch ($matches[0]) {
      case '*':
        return '.*';
      case '?':
        return '.';
      default:
        return '\\'.$matches[0];
    }
  }, $pattern);

  $expr = '/'.$expr.'/';
  if ($ignoreCase) {
    $expr .= 'i';
  }

  return (bool) preg_match($expr, $path);

}
```

**EDIT** Added case-sensitivity option.

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jAB3G7)

Comment: I think this ought to be foolproof. Thanks Dave.

Comment: The "See it working" link takes to a page that just shows a PHP error.

Comment: This is really pretty good. However, it doesn't work correctly. For example, *.js gets converted to "/.*\\.js/". That looks right, but probably is not. The generated regex will match abc.jsx with is probably not what the user wanted. Even worse, the generated regex will match abc/def.js.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add `^` and `$` around the resulting regex? A glob is usually anchored at the beginning and end, while a regex isn't by default.

Comment: Had to add `^` and `$` around the resulting regex as well and modified the  case `'\*': return '[^\\/]*';` to avoid descending into subfolders.

Answer (score 20):

Use [`fnmatch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php), which seems to do the trick.

Comment: That would work, but I need one working on all systems, not POSIX only. +1 for the try though.

Comment: This function is available on Windows since 5.3

Answer (score 5):

There is already a function in PHP, included since PHP 4.3.0.

> [`fnmatch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) checks if the passed string would match the given shell wildcard pattern.

Answer (score 3):

From the PHP documentation for glob(). I think preg_match is the best solution anyway.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

```
<?php   
function match_wildcard( $wildcard_pattern, $haystack ) {
   $regex = str_replace(
     array("\*", "\?"), // wildcard chars
     array('.*','.'),   // regexp chars
     preg_quote($wildcard_pattern)
   );

   return preg_match('/^'.$regex.'$/is', $haystack);
}

$test = "foobar and blob\netc.";
var_dump(
    match_wildcard('foo*', $test),      // TRUE
    match_wildcard('bar*', $test),      // FALSE
    match_wildcard('*bar*', $test),     // TRUE
    match_wildcard('**blob**', $test),  // TRUE
    match_wildcard('*a?d*', $test),     // TRUE
    match_wildcard('*etc**', $test)     // TRUE
);
?>
```

Comment: Yes I considered that `str_replace()` approach, I still can't quite wrap my head around whether it is safe in all cases or not. Also you need to cast the return value of `preg_match()` to a bool, but that is a minor consideration.

Comment: Thats what the preg_quote is for. It will make the entire string regex safe. Then it just makes the * and ? unsafe again. So yes, it does what you want and cant be abused.

Comment: No I know that, it's the subsequent replacements of `\*` and `\?` that I don't like, especially because the subject string/pattern string may legitimately contain backslashes. Also, I've just noticed, you didn't specify a delimiter of `/`.

Comment: I think Dave's concerns are legitimate. If there was a more definite approach, I'd prefer this one over a more complex regex.

Comment: You could always change \* with something like [a-zA-Z0-9\\]

Comment: (Unfortunately "Edit queue is full", so as comment:) This is unsafe as it is. The delimiter needs special treatment by replacing the `preg_quote($wildcard_pattern)` expression with `preg_quote($wildcard_pattern, '/')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for turning glob-patterns into regex-patterns:

```
function glob2regex($globPatt) {
    return '/'.preg_replace_callback('/./u', function($m) {
        switch($m[0]) {
            case '*': return '.*';
            case '?': return '.';
        }
        return preg_quote($m[0],'/');
    }, $globPatt).'\z/AsS';
}
```

You might want to use `[^\\/]*` for `*` instead if you want to prevent `*` from matching over directory names.